# как решить проблему с saveHTML()?

Tags: php, dom

```
  $html = file_get_contents($location);
  $dom  = new DOMDocument;
  $dom->loadHTML($html,  LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED | LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD);
  $el = $dom->getElementById($first);
  $el->parentNode->removeChild($el);
  $b = html_entity_decode($dom->saveHTML());
  file_put_contents($location, $b);
```

Использую saveHTML() для сохранения данных в файл, но данная функция перестраивает структуру кода. Было так:

```
  <div id="1"></div>
  <div id="2"></div>
  <div id="3"></div>
  <div id="4"></div>
```

а после сохранения стало так:

```
  <div id="1">
    <div id="2"></div>
    <div id="4"></div>
  </div>
```

должно быть вот так после сохранения:

```
  <div id="1"></div>
  <div id="2"></div>
  <div id="4"></div>
```

Как это можно исправить?

Comment: не воспроизводится. Приведите [mcve]. Возможно, у вас изначально файл неправильный, коли вы загружаете и сохраняете в один и тот же файл.

Comment: Всё из-за `LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED`

Comment: @RifmaMan есть аналог LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED который отключает автоматическое добавление недостающих html/body... элементов?

Comment: @Li.pro нашел [вот такое решение](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10416704/remove-parent-element-keep-all-inner-children-in-domdocument-with-savehtml) я так понял что обязательно нужен родитель для ваших дивов и чтобы потом его удалить нужно вырезать всё что внутри, пересобрать и вставить обратно, в общем в том примере есть решение, разбирайтесь )

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте так:

```
$html = '<tag>' . $html . '</tag>';
....
$b = str_replace(['<tag>', '</tag>'], '', $dom->saveHTML());
```